# How to POST a nested data and list of image

Tags: json, post, curl, django-rest-framework, imagefield

There are two models: `Product` and `Picture`. Each `Product` can have several `Picture`s. I have questions when I want to create a Product using POST. How to POST a nested object containing a ImageField list?

The `Product` model is:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

The `Picture` model is:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='pictures')
    path = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to='product_pic')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    main = models.BooleanField()
```

I write the serializer.py as follow:

```
class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ('path', 'description', 'main')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    pictures = PictureSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_id', 'product_name', 'pictures', 'description')
```

The view that I am using is:

```
class ProductEnum(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am registering it in the urls as:

```
url(r'^api/products/$', views.ProductEnum.as_view()),
```

The questions are:

- How could I test this POST api as `django-rest-framework` tells me that "Lists are not currently supported in HTML input"
- How to use JSON to POST a `Product` resources with multiple `Pictures`. OR I must use multipart parser.
- How to write cURL command?

Comment: did you manage to get it right?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use multipart parser, as soon as you need to send binary data you basically only have to choices:

1. weaken your REST approach and make an exception -> json cannot hold binary data
2. encode every binary file with base64, keep json approach but you need to do de/encoding additionally for every request (not natively supported)

An approach that can be seen quite often is to create an (non rest) view to upload single/multiple files which create `File` or `Document` objects (returning an id on upload). Then you can use these id(s) which another request, in your case creating/updating your `Product`.

In general there is no easy way to do that because json doesn't support binary data.

Answer (score 1):

DRF makes this quite easy to do. You are close, you need to override `ProductSerializer.create`, something like this:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    pictures = PictureSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_id', 'product_name', 'pictures', 'description')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Pop this from the validated_data first, since the serializer can't handle it.
        pictures = validated_data.pop('pictures')
        product = super().create(validated_data)
        # Now that we have a product to reference in the FKey, create the pictures.
        for picture in pictures:
            # `picture` has been run through the PictureSerialzer, so it's valid. 
            picture['product'] = product
            Picture.objects.create(**picture)
        return product
```

There's a full example in the docs, here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

For your `curl` command, it's going to be something like:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/products/ -H 'ContentType: application/json' -d '{"pictures": [{"description": "first one"}, {"description": "second one"}], "product_name": "foobar"}'`

Comment: hi there, I did as you do, but doesn't work. please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use manage.py shell.
Like this:

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/login/url", data={"username": "username", "password": "password"}
r.content (outputs token)
token="yourtoken"
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/your/url", data={your POST data in json}, headers={"Authorization": "Token %s" % token})
```

Comment: You didn't answer the poster's golden question - How to use JSON to POST a Product resources with multiple Pictures. OR I must use multipart parser.